# CVXPY Unable to find suitable interval for bisection

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

I have a simple optimization problem and I'm using CVXPY to solve it. Here is the code:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

x = cp.Variable()
concave_fn = cp.log(cp.log(1+cp.exp(x)))
constraints = [x <= 2]
problem = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(concave_fn), constraints)
assert problem.is_dqcp()
problem.solve(qcp=True, verbose=True)
```

However it gives the followong error:

```
SolverError: Unable to find suitable interval for bisection.
```

I don't have any idea what the source of this error is.

Comment: Wild guess: does it help to put a lower bound on x? Or is the default lower bound 0 (I don't know cvxpy)? Or put the bounds explicitly on the variable rather than writing it as a constraint.

Comment: @DanielJunglas Thank you for your comment. No, it gives the same error after adding a lower bound.

Comment: The problem you posted is a bit outside the cvxpy wheelhouse. A more standard way to express it is ``maximize log_sum_exp(cp.hstack([0, x]))`` subject to ``x <= 2``. That will not involve bisection.